# How to send an email on behalf of someone else from a different domain

Tags: email, smtp, html-email, sendgrid

I am building an e-commerce website (let's call it e-buy.com). What I want is a mailing system where buyer can send an email to seller... so for example, I would have to send an email like this:

```
from: buyer1@yahoo.com
to: seller1@gmail.com
subject: buyer inquiry via e-buy.com
```

I have built the above solution, but sometimes my emails are not delivered... the reason (as far as I know) is that I am sending an email from: `e-buy.com` domain but the sender is from a different domain: `buyer1@yahoo.com`

**Question 1>** Is this a bad practice to set the from field to a domain different from the mail server's domain?

---

I have seen some websites implement the following solution in the same situation:

```
from: mailer@e-buy.com
to: seller1@gmail.com
subject: buyer inquiry via e-buy.com e-commerce
```

So email is coming from: `mailer@e-buy.com`, but when the seller clicks on reply button, the reply automatically changes from `mailer@e-buy.com` to `buyer1@yahoo.com`

**Question 2>** How can this switching of sender's email be implemented?

Comment: If the domain dosnt have DKIM setup to say sat this sendgrid account can sent on your behalf, email clients will see it as spam.

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup: thanks for this... it is not practical to expect `person@gmail.com` sets up DKIM, saying that Sendgrid will send emails on your behalf, so I believe you are saying I need to use the `reply-to` option as explained in the accepted answer?

Comment: So you have the domain e-buy.com, but want to sent the mail from a seller@yahoo.com? Or is it only when people reply to the email it should go to seller@yahoo.com?

Comment: correct, my e-commerce domain is `e-buy.com`. When a buyer with email `buyer@yahoo.com` wants to buy a product from seller with email `seller@yahoo.com`, I need to send an email to the seller, and the seller should be able to reply to the buyer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:**
When sending emails from another domain - you need to keep in mind that they will need to setup DNS records to list your mail server / sender as a legitimate email sender, seeming as you'll most likely have multiple *big brand* domains (gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc), this approach is most likely not what you want.

**Answer 2:**
This is more realistic and quite easy to implement. What you're looking for is a `reply-to` header. This will specify what email users should be sending to when they try to reply to an email.

Explained further [here](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/220568427-What-is-a-Reply-To-address-).

> When you send an email to a subscriber and they click 'Reply', the
>   reply message is typically sent to the email address listed in the
>   From: header.
>
> A Reply-To address is identified by inserting the Reply-To header in
>   your email. It is the email address that the reply message is sent
>   when you want the reply to go to an email address that is different
>   than the From: address.
>
> In the example below, 'service@sampledomain.com' is the Reply-To
>   address. When a subscriber clicks 'Reply', the reply message is sent
>   to 'service@sampledomain.com' instead of 'marketing@sampledomain.com'.
>
> From: marketing@sampledomain.com
>
> to: aaasample@zzzexample.com